# Initializing a recurrent neural network (RNN) in Keras

Tags: keras, rnn

When we create an RNN in Keras, does it learn an initial hidden layer (ie. $h_0$, like a bias term)? I'm having trouble figuring this out, but I have looked [here](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/).

Can anyone highlight a part in the code that shows an initial hidden layer is being learned? Or is it just randomly initializing the hidden layer?

EDIT: The code is [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py) , I'm just having trouble identifying where the hidden layer is initialized and what it is initialized to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 809, you can find that `SimpleRNNCell` takes a `bias_initializer` as an argument to the constructor function and it defaults to `zeros`.